# How to obtain the correct interpolation for the following data?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, interpolation, data

I have a dataset [DistrTemp.dat](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8w9du5af0ztv9wf/DistrTemp.dat?dl=0). It represents a set of data in the form `{{x,y,z,f[x,y,z]}}`. Here, x defines a system, while `f[x,y,z]` is a probability to find some system in the vicinity of `y,z` and has a property 
$$
\int \limits_{0}^{\pi} dy \int \limits_{x}^{3500} dz \ f(x,y,z) = 1
$$
My goal is to obtain continuous function F[x,y,z] that I can use for the integration measure.

I try to interpolate the dataset for particular values of x:

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]
DistrData = Import["DistrTemp.dat","Table"];
DistrInterpolation005[\[Theta]S_, ES_] = 
 Interpolation[{Log10[#[[2]]], Log10[#[[3]]], #[[4]]} & /@ 
    Select[DistrData, #[[1]] == 0.05 &], InterpolationOrder -> 1][
  Log10[\[Theta]S], Log10[ES]]
```

Then I compare the obtainted interpolation with the initial dataset:

```
Plot3D[DistrInterpolation005[\[Theta]S, 10^(ES)], {\[Theta]S, 0, 
  Pi}, {ES, Log10[0.05], Log10[3500]}, ImageSize -> Large, 
 PlotRange -> All]
ListPlot3D[{#[[2]], Log10[#[[3]]], #[[4]]} & /@ 
  Select[DistrData, #[[1]] == 0.05 &], PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Red], ImageSize -> Large]
```

I find that the interpolation has been done incorrectly, since some domains are lost, while some domains are overestimated:

[image]

I tried to use WeightedData:

```
TableCoordinates = Select[DistrData, #[[1]] == 0.05 &][[All, {2, 3}]]
TableWeights = Flatten[DataTemp[[All, 4]]]
F1 = WeightedData[TableCoordinates, TableWeights]
DistrWeighted = 
 Table[f[F1], {f, {HistogramDistribution, SmoothKernelDistribution, 
    EmpiricalDistribution}}]
Table[Plot3D[
  PDF[i, {\[Theta]S, Log10[ES]}], {ES, Log10[0.05], 
   Log10[3500]}, {\[Theta]S, 0, Pi}, 
  PlotLabel -> Row[{"Mean: ", Mean[i]}], ImageSize -> Large], {i, 
  DistrWeighted}]
```

However, neither of the distributions match the desired distribution:

[image]

How to construct the interpolation correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Interpolation`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interpolation.html) does fit all the points, which suggests that it probably is a plotting resolution issue.  Try a higher number of PlotPoints.  For example,

```
lp = ListPlot3D[{#[[2]], Log10[#[[3]]], #[[4]]} & /@ 
    Select[DistrData, #[[1]] == 0.05 &], PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotStyle -> {Directive[Green], Opacity[0.5]}, ImageSize -> Large];
plt = Plot3D[
   DistrInterpolation005[\[Theta]S, 10^(ES)], {\[Theta]S, 0, Pi}, {ES,
     Log10[0.05], Log10[3500]}, ImageSize -> Large, PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotPoints -> 400];
Show[lp, plt]
```

[image]